# CodeIgniter Url rewriting similar to Pinterest and Twitter

Tags: codeigniter, twitter, url-rewriting, pinterest

I have just started with CodeIgniter and I am creating a website where users log in. I want to know how I can write custom names to the URL of a logged in user similar to twitter and pinterest based on the logged in user's username.

http://pinterest.com/username/

currently i have a profile controller and it simply has;

http://example.com/profile/

for each user. Is it possible with codeigniter to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output the link you can use [CI's URL helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

You have to autoload it, that would be under `config/autoload.php` :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

or load it from your function :

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then you can output links like `http://example.com/profile/` by using `anchor()` :

```
$username = 'Corey'; // Set the user's name
anchor($username);
```

That will output :

http://example.com/corey/

I assume you don't want to create a function in the controller for each user in your database. Add the magic method __call() to your controller and redirect to your profile function with the user's name as parameter :

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    $this->profile($name);
}
```

But that's not enough, you will have to do a little bit of route hacking also. [See Minimize your URLs in CodeIgniter](http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-minimize-url-and-remove-index-php/).

Comment: Ok I'm working on what you have shown me, I will get back to you with progress :)

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in what you come up to :-)

Comment: From your link wouldn't it be best to just create a function in the profile controller "profile/getuser/args" and route out the "profile/getuser" method from the url?

Comment: Yes, then you don't even need the magic __call if that is what you mean.

Comment: yeah I'm just too green still lol, but I do want to do things the right way, cheers for your help mate :)

Comment: Still couldn't get it working :( there needs to be an easier way. When I use http://example.com/username it doesn't set of the remap function on the default controller for some reason

Comment: @CoreyLylyk, could you explain precisely what you did so far and what is or isn't working?

Comment: Got it working with the remap function in the default controller :)